# load shipping custom field value by entity_metawrapper

Tags: commerce, entities

I add some field to shipping and billing information, in payment stage of checkout I want load order billing information,I know I can load it by

```
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $billing_info = $order_wrapper->commerce_customer_billing->commerce_customer_address->value();
  $shipping_info = $order_wrapper->commerce_customer_shipping->commerce_customer_address->value();
```

when I goto `en/admin/commerce/customer-profiles/414`  I see my filled up information,but when I try to `dpm` them in code(my custom payment gatway)  it did not load my custom field values. is it the bug of  `entity_metadata_wrapper` or I did some mistakes?
and finally how can I load my custom field correctly?

**Update**

I use below method to get my fields and work

```
    $profile_id=$order->commerce_customer_billing['und'][0]['profile_id'];
      $profile = commerce_customer_profile_load($profile_id);
      //dpm($profile);
  $billing_info['thoroughfare']=$profile->field_full_address['und'][0]['value'];
```

but really want to know  `entity_meta_data_wrapper` can't load them and it is a bug on it or if can what is the solution?

Comment: Have you tried `$order_wrapper->commerce_customer_billing->commerce_customer_address->yourCustomField->value()` or `$order_wrapper->commerce_customer_billing->yourCustomField->value()`?
You can't dpm entity wrapper directly but you can use `getPropertyInfo()` on each level to see properties inside current entity. Try `$order_wrapper->commerce_customer_billing->getPropertyInfo()`

Comment: I try both and both return error, and when try `$order_wrapper->commerce_customer_billing->getPropertyInfo()` there is not my custom field there